# Sorting Dates in Custom Google Sheets Calendar

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to populate a calendar with google sheets in the following way :

I have a sheet called processing which has all the projects and their dates (some use one date and some use up until 14 consecutive days).  And then I have a sheet called Calendar with the actual calendar to filter all the dates.

I would like to display the project name for every calendar day that it is booked in the processing sheet.

**Please see below screenshots**

[image: Calendar test 1]
[image: Calendar test 2]

**Processing sheet :**

[image: Processing Sheet]

Here is the closest to working function I have tried :

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(Processing!$A$3:$V,"select A where E = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or F = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or G = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or H = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or I = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or H = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or J = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or K = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or L = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or M = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or N = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or O = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or P = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or Q = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or R = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or S = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or T = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or U = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' or V = date '"&text(H4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1),"")
```

*So basically* on the Calendar I want to reflect/filter all values in Processing sheets column A's value that has a date matching the calendar day - so far it works only for every project's first day - but not all days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Spreadsheet Link**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sowkIl_BcsbPoc9PUMZHL2bM7-XNMql2dV3yJo58-Sc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clearly indicating the expected output? Also, since you tagged `google-apps-script`, I assume you are open to using Apps Script for this?

Comment: Yes I am open to use App Script. Thanks, I added a link to the spreadsheet in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, using Apps Script:

- Store an object based on the data in `Processing`, in which the keys refer to the different dates, and the values are arrays with the different projects (in the code below, that's called `datesAndProjects`).
- Using the A1 notation where the dates are located in `Calendar` (that is, `B4:K4`, `B16:K16`, `B28:K28`), loop through the different dates, and for each date, find the corresponding property in `datesAndProjects` and write the corresponding values (the projects) in that column.

Below is a detailed example of how this can be done (check inline comments for more in-depth explanation).

#### Code snippet:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function projectToCalendar() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processing");
  const sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let datesAndProjects = {};
  sourceData.forEach(row => { // Iterate through each row in "Processing"
    const project = row.shift(); // Retrieve first value in each row (project names)
    row.forEach(val => {
      if (val instanceof Date) { // Check if value is Date
        const time = getDayTime(val); // Convert date to milliseconds since Epoch in order to compare them
        if (!datesAndProjects[time]) datesAndProjects[time] = []; // Inititalize property if it doesn't exist
        datesAndProjects[time].push([project]); // Add project to date
      }
    });
  });
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar");
  const dateRangeNotations = ["B4:K4", "B16:K16", "B28:K28"]; // A1 notations where dates are located
  targetSheet.getRangeList(dateRangeNotations).getRanges().forEach(range => { // Iterate through each row with dates
    const times = range.getValues()[0].map(date => getDayTime(date)); // Get ms since Epoch in order to compare dates
    times.forEach((time, i) => { // Iterate each date (ms)
      if (datesAndProjects[time]) { // Check if property exists
        targetSheet.getRange(range.getRow() + 2, range.getColumn() + i, datesAndProjects[time].length).setValues(datesAndProjects[time]); // Write values at corresponding column, starting two rows after date cell
      }
    });
  });
}

function getDayTime(date) {
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()).getTime();
}
```

#### Note:

- In this snippet, `setValues` is being called inside a loop, something which is not optimal for efficiency purposes. This could probably be improved, but I think this snippet is enough for you to get the idea.

Comment: @JacquesNaudé You're welcome, glad your issue was solved!